# Image recognition: find area containing number on payment card

Tags: android, ios, image-processing

I have an image of a payment card. There is a limited number of cards that are accepted and ?I know how each card looks like. I know, in millimeters, where is the bank account number on the card.

The user takes a photo of the card with his phone. I do not know how the photo is taken. It could be the camera is a bit turned. I do not know if the camera is zoomed in, I do not know the distance of the camera to the card.

What I want to do is to blur the bank account number. So, 1) find the area where the bank account number is 2) blur this area.

I was wondering how this can be done. As I have some knowledge about the card, can I use that knowledge. The software has to run on a mobile phone, so the image recognition part cannot take to long.

I hope someone can point me to some algorithms or further reading material. So far I have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: I sadly cannot help you with any algorithms but are the colors of the numbers consistent? If so you could try finding clusters of pixels containing this color and blurring them. This is a workaround in its sense, you have to decide whether it fits your use case. Image recognition is a bit compilcated, but maybe you can use OpenCV to find the card in a picture.

Comment: Maybe that could work. I know in which area to look. I could use the nearest neighbour algorithm to make a block linking the numbes together. Sounds like it could work.